# como adicionar um valor por parâmetro a uma select statement in sql dentro de uma função simple table-valued?

Tags: sql, sql-server

este é o meu código e queria adicionar um valor a uma instrução de select que é passado por parâmetro para uma função de simple table valued.
Aqui está o meu código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NMELHORESFORNECEDORES(@N INT )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN SELECT TOP @N/*da erro nesta variavel*/  IDFornecedor AS FORNECEDOR, Nome,TotalFactura FROM Fornecedores
JOIN Facturas ON Facturas.Fornecedor=Fornecedores.IDFornecedor
ORDER BY Nome DESC
```

o erro esta na variável @N na statement SELECT a seguir ao RETURN, não consigo concatenar de maneira nenhuma o valor com a statement.
como é que eu posso fazer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessario pôr a expressão em parênteses.

Veja Books Online > TOP (Transact-SQL) -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Por exemplo, este codigo funciona:

```
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_MelhoresFornecedores
(
    @porcento int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP (@porcento) PERCENT V.AccountNumber, V.Name, SUM(H.TotalDue) AS 'Total'
        FROM Purchasing.Vendor AS V
            INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS H
                ON H.VendorID = V.BusinessEntityID
        GROUP BY V.AccountNumber, V.Name
        ORDER BY Total DESC
);
```

Para testar a função, com 10% por exemplo:

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.uf_MelhoresFornecedores(10);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]